# Java generics - strange behavior of Java Compiler

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, javac

I have an created an Interface `HTMLlizeable` and implemented this Interface in currently two classes (`Course implements HTMLlizeable` and `Student implements HTMLlizeable`)

The `loadAll` Method looks like this :

```
public ArrayList<Course> loadAll(){...}
```

Now if i try to compile this line

```
ArrayList<HTMLlizeable>courses=this.db.getCourseLoader().loadAll();
```

javac or eclipse in my case always gives me this error ...

`Cannot cast from ArrayList<Course> to ArrayList<HTMLlizeable>`

.. and i have no idea why because Course implements HTMLlizeable. What am I doing wrong - or is this a limitation of the Generics in Java. The same thing happens btw with Student too.

Comment: Short answer: "learn java".  Java generics are not C++ templates. `List<Course>` is not `List<HTMLlizeable>`.   Browse to here and read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/  There is a section on Generics.

Comment: @DwB - I'd imagine that the entry-level tutorial won't cover the issue of covariance, though.

Comment: Imagine this, The `Course` and `Student` classes can have additional methods than `HTMLlizeable`, How are those methods reachable if you are casting it to HtmlLizeable?

Comment: @ajc - How is that concern different to the case of a straightforward `HTMLlizeable h = new Course(...)`?

Comment: Found a simple solution. ArrayList<? extends HTMLlizeable>. This works.

Comment: @T.Furholzer - Be careful with that, though.  You won't be able to do (for example) `courses.add(new Course(...))` if `courses` is of type `ArrayList<? extends HTMLlizeable>`.